# neo4j way to store users' input for decision tree

Tags: spring, data-structures, neo4j

I'm new to neo4j and what to know what's the "neo4j" way to handle this kind of situation.

I've a decision tree, and for each node of the tree, there might have some inputs.
below code is the tree node.(for each node, I will have another class to extends the basenode to override the eval)

```
@Data
@NodeEntity
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true, access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
public class BaseNode {
    @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String guide;
    //private String refDocuments;
    @Relationship(type = "HAS_REFDOC") private List<RefDocument> refDocuments;
    private String remark;
    @Relationship(type = "HAS_INPUT") private List<InputField> inputFields;
    public boolean eval() {
    }
}
```

and each node will use a relationship "CONN" to point to his children.

And now when the user come in, I need to store the user input data, I come out 2 ways to store the user data, but just can't config out what's the right way, or either of them is correct.

1. for each user, I create a new decision tree for him, so that it would be convenient to store the user input and get the current position in the tree, but I'm not sure if the index can cover and speed up most of the queries, let's said I want to search all the users that end up select one of the leaf, would that work?
2. for each user, I create a node for him, and then use the relationship to point to the tree node, the relationship itself has the input as properties. This structure may easily solve my earlier question, but the new question come to my mind is that if this is the case, the tree nodes may have millions of relationship or even more, will that cause a problem?

Comment: Check out https://maxdemarzi.com/tag/decision-tree/

Comment: thank you for your response, it's helpful by fanning out the relationships.